# Table heading and body layout

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have my table heading and table body contents all typed out in html but the contents of the table body are all showing on only one of the headings on the webpage. How do I fix this so the body content are under their correct headings? Here is my code.

```html
<thead>
  <th>Nursery</th>
  <th>Life Kids</th>
  <th>Thrive Youth</th>
  <th>Adult Bible Study</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Ages 0-Preschool<br>Availiable during all services</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>K-5th Grade<br>Sundays @10am & Wednesdays @6:30pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6th-12th Grade<br>Wednesdays @6:30pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Adults<br>Wednesdays @6:30pm</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Firstly your snippet is missing the <table></table> tag. And then in the tbody you have 4 rows (<tr></tr>) rather than one row with 4 columns (<td></td>)

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything to be aligned properly, you need one `td` for each `th`, here you  have 4 `th`s but only 1 `td` per row.

Perhaps you are confusing `tr`with`td`?

Please consult examples here for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 0):

## fixed version of your code:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Nursery</th>
  <th>Life Kids</th>
  <th>Thrive Youth</th>
  <th>Adult Bible Study</th>
</tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Ages 0-Preschool<br>Availiable during all services</td>
    <td>K-5th Grade<br>Sundays @10am & Wednesdays @6:30pm</td>
    <td>6th-12th Grade<br>Wednesdays @6:30pm</td>
    <td>Adults<br>Wednesdays @6:30pm</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### and you can style it with this css code:

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more explanation with every code snippet. What's the concept behind those html table tags tr, td, etc. that require such arrangement?